# BestPractice to Confirm Delete data from mongodb using springData

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Just want to confirm the mechanism via which it can be confirmed that data has been deleted successfully from MongoDB.

By using following code I am able to delete a record successfully from the mongodb

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(id));
MongoConfig.getMongoTemplate().remove(query, Person.class);
```

But what if a record with provided id do not exist in the database. Even in that case mongoDB doesn't gives any error.

Now if I try to check that whether there was any error on not by using following code:

```
MongoConfig.getMongoTemplate().getDb().getLastError()
```

I am not too sure that in a multi threaded environment, what is the possibility that the error which is returned by mongodb if present is related to delete operation only.

As per second approach, first loading object with the provided id and then deleting it doesn't makes much sense to you as there will be unnecessary 2 queries will be fired.

Any pointers/help on same is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. MongoDB Java API is thread-aware/safe and multi-threading should not cause any issues with checking getLastError on the connection you did the remove.
2. If you are using newer version of API, it is very likely by default the getLastError check is already being done. What is the version of your API?